# Copy MySQL data files to another instance to bypass password

Tags: security, mysql

Is it possible to copy the MySQL data files for a specific table/database to another instance of MySQL to bypass user/password permissions?

For example on 1st instance there is a database that only user A can have access to. If an attacker managed to get a copy of my MySQL data files, will he be able to install those files (table/database related ones only) to his own MySQL instance, and read the database using his own user that has permissions to that table?

Comment: It depends I think though.... If you are using, [InnoDB Tablespace Encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html) features and such then it states that "*InnoDB supports data encryption for tables stored in file-per-table tablespaces. This feature provides at-rest encryption for physical tablespace data files.*" so in this scenario, it's not as simple as copy it to another instance, attach, and then gain access I don't think so it depends on your MySQL version and configuration with this regard to be accurate.

Comment: That was informative. thanks! guess i'll have to check tablespace encryption, or just let the software handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Password and privilege checks **are not encryption** – they are voluntary on mysqld's part. An attacker could patch the database engine to bypass password checks, or just use the existing documented password-reset methods. mysqld even has [a command-line option](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqld+skip-grant-tables) for this!